# Draw Circles on Top Level of Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a figure where I'm trying to draw a circle on top of a combination colormap and contour plot. The circle keeps getting drawn under the contours instead of on top of them (see the figure below). I've tried reordering how I call imshow, contour, and Circle to see if I can get the circle to display on top, but I haven't had any luck. Is there a way to force Circle to be on the top most level of the figure? Thanks for your help!

[image: Colormap with contour plot and added circle]

Comment: we can't read in your mind - show your code.

Comment: mostly to draw two elements in one place you have to use the same figure or axes (I don't remember)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`zorder` kwarg](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder). That controls which elements go on top of each other. So, in this case, you want to increase the `zorder` of the circle. You may need to experiment to find a `zorder` that gives you the result you require, but the rule is that higher `zorder` objects appear on top of lower `zorder` objects.

Its hard to know exactly without any of your code, but assuming you've used `pcolormesh`, `contour` and a `Circle` patch, this example shows the effect of not setting a `zorder` (white circle), and setting `zorder=10` (red circle).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

# Fake data
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = X**0.5 * Y**0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, z, cmap='viridis')
ax.contour(X, Y, z, colors='k', linewidths=3)

circ1 = Circle((65, 65), 30, facecolor='None', edgecolor='w', lw=5)
circ2 = Circle((35, 35), 30, facecolor='None', edgecolor='r', lw=5, zorder=10)

ax.add_patch(circ1)
ax.add_patch(circ2)

plt.show()
```

Note that the white circle lies beneath the black contour lines, but by increasing the `zorder` to 10, the red circle lies on top of the contour lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`zorder`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) property of the plot object to force it to be on top of other plots within the same `axes`. A higher `zorder` value will appear on top of a lower `zorder` value.

```
plt.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], zorder=100)
```

By default, patches have a `zorder` of 1, 2D line objects have a `zorder` of 2 and text has a `zorder` of 3.