# matplotlib seaborn heatmap x,y meshgrid logscale issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, xticks

So my problem is, that I would like to plot several heatmaps as a multiplot, where I have the X,Y axis logarithmic, and also add patches to the heatmap, to highlight certain areas with tuning alpha values (see attached image).
The thing is, that with pcolormesh, you can easily use logscale for X,Y because it uses the exact data to show, however seaborn can just use the indexes of the data.
On the other hand with pcolormesh I did not find a way to add pacthes, but with seaborn it is easy to do...

So I would like to come up with a solution where both the logarithmic scaling and adding pacthes to plot could be done...

I add a part of the code and I attach an image what I could do with seaborn yet.

So here is the code for the seaborn heatmap multiplot with sime custom x,ytics done in jupyter-notebook:

```py
def HeatMapPlotter(alphaval,im_w,im_h,tissue_type,hl_x_min,hl_x_max,hl_y_min,hl_y_max): # alpha value of heatmap highlights, image width and height, type of tissue: blood or colon


    data_type = ["n","gamma","d","r0"]
    c_labels =["$n_\mathrm{drift}$","$\gamma_\mathrm{drift}$","$d_\mathrm{drift}$","$r_0^\mathrm{drift}$"] 
    vminR = [0.99,1.99,0.99,1e-4]
    sb.set_style('white', {'axes.linewidth': 0.5})
    plt.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 20
    plt.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 4
    plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = True
    plt.rcParams['ytick.left'] = True
    
    if tissue_type=="blood":
        points = p_b
        n_points = n_p_b
        Ns = Nsb
        mus = musb
        Nsl = ['{:.1e}'.format(i) for i in Nsb]
        Nsl = [reformatE(i) for i in Nsl]
        musl = ['{:.1e}'.format(j) for j in musb]
        musl = [reformatE(i) for i in musl]
    else:
        points = p_c
        n_points = n_p_c        
        Ns = Nsc
        mus = musc
        Nsl = ['{:.1e}'.format(i) for i in Nsc]
        Nsl = [reformatE(i) for i in Nsl]
        musl = ['{:.1e}'.format(j) for j in musc]
        musl = [reformatE(i) for i in musl]
        
    dataColl = [0]*8
    d_index = 0
    for d in range(8):

        if d_index==4:
            d_index=0

        if d<4:

            dataColl[d] = array([point[data_type[d_index]] for point in points]).reshape(RES,RES)
        else:

            dataColl[d] = array([point[data_type[d_index]] for point in n_points]).reshape(RES,RES)

        d_index+=1

    y, x = np.meshgrid(mus, Ns)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(im_w,im_h), nrows=2, ncols=4);

    m_index=0
    #fig.suptitle(tissue_type+" "+"scd (top) and neutral (bottom)") 

    for m, ax in zip(range(0,8), axes.flat):
        plt.figure(m);
        sb.set(font_scale=cb_scale);  # set colorbar font scale
        
        
        if m_index==4:
            m_index=0
        if m==3 or m==7:
            sb.heatmap(dataColl[m], cmap = ListedColormap(newcolors),norm=LogNorm(),cbar_kws={'label': c_labels[m_index]},vmin=vminR[m_index], vmax=amax(dataColl[m]),ax=ax)
        else:
            sb.heatmap(dataColl[m], cmap = ListedColormap(newcolors),cbar_kws={'label': c_labels[m_index]},vmin=vminR[m_index], vmax=amax(dataColl[m]),ax=ax)
        if m%4==0:
            
            ax.set_ylabel("$\mu$",fontsize=mu_l_s);
        else:
            ax.set_ylabel(" ",fontsize=mu_l_s);

        ax.set_xticklabels(Nsl,rotation=x_rot); #set xtics label (default is 0,1,2...)
        ax.set_yticklabels(musl,rotation=y_rot); #set ytics label (default is 0,1,2...)            
            

        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels()[1::2], visible=False);  # every 2nd tic is highlighted for xtics
        plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels()[1::2], visible=False);  # every 2nd tic is highlighted for ytics  
        ax.set_xlabel("\n$N$",fontsize=N_l_s); # set xlabel   
        ax.tick_params(direction='out', length=16, width=6, colors='black',
               grid_color='black', grid_alpha=1.0,labelsize=tick_ls);     # tick settings
        
        
        # set the highlighted box and set alpha by user input (see description in a cell below)
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((hl_x_min, hl_y_min), hl_x_max-hl_x_min, hl_y_max-hl_y_min, fill=False, edgecolor='black', linestyle = '--',  lw=5,alpha=1.0));
        for r in range(RES):
            for c in range(RES):
                if (r>=hl_x_min and r<hl_x_max) and (c<hl_y_max and c>=hl_y_min):
                    continue
                else:
                    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((r, c), 1, 1, fill=True, color = 'gray', edgecolor=None, lw=0, alpha=alphaval));

        m_index +=1
    plt.tight_layout();
```

and the code for the pcolormesh version, where logscale working and add patches not...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib as mpl

data_type = ["n","gamma","d","r0"]
c_labels =["$n_\mathrm{drift}$","$\gamma_\mathrm{drift}$","$d_\mathrm{drift}$","$r_0^\mathrm{drift}$"] 
vminR = [1.0,1.99,1.0,1e-4]


hl_x_min,hl_x_max,hl_y_min,hl_y_max = 3,10,2,8

alphaval = 0.6

labels_size = 24 # X,Y,Z labels size

cb_ts = 15 # colorbar tick number font size

tick_ls = 15

title_s = 60 # size of title
im_w,im_h = 40,12  # image width and height
cb_scale = 4.8   # scale of colorbar font size
x_rot,y_rot = 90,0  # rotation of x and y tick labels

dataColl = [0]*8
d_index = 0
for d in range(8):

    if d_index==4:
        d_index=0

    if d<4:

        dataColl[d] = array([point[data_type[d_index]] for point in points]).reshape(RES,RES)
    else:

        dataColl[d] = array([point[data_type[d_index]] for point in n_points]).reshape(RES,RES)

    d_index+=1


fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(im_w,im_h), nrows=2, ncols=4);

m_index=0
#fig.suptitle(tissue_type+" "+"scd (top) and neutral (bottom)") 

fig.text(0.483,0.86,"blood \n \n",fontsize = 35)
fig.text(0.488,0.82,"scd \n \n",fontsize = 35)
fig.text(0.48,0.38,"neutral \n \n",fontsize = 35)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.5) 

for m, ax in zip(range(0,8), axes.flat):
    
    y, x = np.meshgrid(mus, Ns)
    z = dataColl[m]
    z=z.T
    
    if m_index==4:
        m_index=0
    
    if m==3 or m==7:
        cmesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z,norm=LogNorm(),cmap=ListedColormap(newcolors),vmin=vminR[m_index],vmax=amax(z),antialiased=True, shading="nearest" , snap=True,edgecolors="face") 
    else:
        cmesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z,cmap=ListedColormap(newcolors),vmin=vminR[m_index],vmax=amax(z),antialiased=True, shading="nearest" , snap=True,edgecolors="face") 
    cb=fig.colorbar(cmesh,ax=ax)
    cb.set_label(label=c_labels[m_index],fontsize=labels_size,rotation = 90)

    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.tick_params(direction='out', length=4, width=2, colors='black',
       grid_color='black', grid_alpha=1.0,labelsize=tick_ls);     # tick settings
        
    cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=cb_ts)
    
    
    if m>3:
        ax.set_xlabel("$N$",fontsize=labels_size)
    if m_index ==0:
        ax.set_ylabel("$\mu$",fontsize=labels_size)
    
    # set the highlighted box and set alpha by user input (see description in a cell below)
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((hl_x_min, hl_y_min), hl_x_max-hl_x_min, hl_y_max-hl_y_min, fill=False, edgecolor='black', linestyle = '--',  lw=5,alpha=1.0));
    for r in range(RES):
        for c in range(RES):
            if (r>=hl_x_min and r<hl_x_max) and (c<hl_y_max and c>=hl_y_min):
                continue
            else:
                ax.add_patch(Rectangle((r, c), 1, 1, fill=True, color = 'gray', edgecolor=None, lw=0, alpha=alphaval));
    m_index +=1


#plt.tight_layout();

plt.show()

fig.savefig("pcmesh.pdf")
```

Hope it is understandable, I tried to search for this problem, I've read a ton of stuff, yet I could not find anything...

Thank you in advance!
[image: This is the seaborn plot]

[image: And this is the pcolormesh version, where the logscale tics matter]

Comment: > "On the other hand with pcolormesh I did not find a way to add pacthes, but with seaborn it is easy to do..." Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib. `ax.add_patch(Rectangle(...))` is matplotlib code. Where exactly is the issue?

Comment: The issue is, that if i try to add patches, as you also pointed out, they simply does not appear when pcolormesh is applied, and they appear when seaborn is beeing used... I provide a code for that case also..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after even more hours of search I have found the solution.
My mistake was that I treated add_patch() with pcolormesh, as it would use index coordinates and not the actual X,Y meshgrid data, and I had to add zorder >0 to the Rectangle() function.

Citing this question here: [Draw Circles on Top Level of Figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638229/draw-circles-on-top-level-of-figure)

```py
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((hl_x_min, hl_y_min), hl_x_max-hl_x_min, hl_y_max-hl_y_min, fill=False, edgecolor='black', linestyle = '--',  lw=5,alpha=1.0,zorder = 10));
```

and `(hl_x_min, hl_y_min), hl_x_max-hl_x_min, hl_y_max-hl_y_min` coordinates has to be given as not indexes (0,1,2...) but actual data intervals (like (1e-4;1e-2) ).